# PHP JSON Trying to get sale id from JSON data

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to extract the sales id from the following JSON code in php.  The output I'm trying to get is:

```
1KE4800207592173L
```

JSON Code.

```
{
  "transactions": [
  {
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
    "related_resources": [
    {
      "sale":
      {
        "id": "1KE4800207592173L",
        "create_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:26Z",
        "update_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:28Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "parent_payment": "PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
        "links": [
        {
          "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1KE4800207592173L",
          "rel": "self",
          "method": "GET"
        }]
      }
    }]
  }],
  "links": [
  {
    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY- 34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
    "rel": "self",
    "method": "GET"
  }]
}
```

Any help in trying to get this as a PHP JSON or Array reference would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

---

EDIT:

I've tried the following:

```
$response1 = json_decode($response);
$payment_id = $response1->transactions->related_resources->sale->id;
$payment_id = print_r($payment_id, true);
```

And

```
$response1 = json_decode($response);
$payment_id = $response1->transactions->related_resources[0]->sale->id;
$payment_id = print_r($payment_id, true);
```

neither seem to work.

Original JSON is the same as what can be found here. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/execute-payments/ if that helps.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post a [inimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: use json_decode($jsonScriptVariable, true); it will convert into array and then you can easily access.

Comment: ok edited above with what I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

try this

use **json_decode** which converts the json string in to object

```
 $a = '{
      "transactions": [
      {
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
        "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale":
          {
            "id": "1KE4800207592173L",
            "create_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:26Z",
            "update_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:28Z",
            "state": "completed",
            "parent_payment": "PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
            "links": [
            {
              "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1KE4800207592173L",
              "rel": "self",
              "method": "GET"
            }]
          }
        }]
      }],
      "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY- 34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
      }]
    }';



    print_r(json_decode($a)->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$array = json_decode($jsonScriptVariable, true);
```

it will convert into array and then you can easily access.

```
<?php
$var = '{
  "transactions": [
  {
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
    "related_resources": [
    {
      "sale":
      {
        "id": "1KE4800207592173L",
        "create_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:26Z",
        "update_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:28Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "parent_payment": "PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
        "links": [
        {
          "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1KE4800207592173L",
          "rel": "self",
          "method": "GET"
        }]
      }
    }]
  }],
  "links": [
  {
    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY- 34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
    "rel": "self",
    "method": "GET"
  }]
}';

$array = json_decode($var, true);
echo $array['transactions'][0]['related_resources'][0]['sale']['id'];
```

you can use simple **json_decode($var);** that will give you object and you can access like

```
echo $array->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->id;
```